# cant find intrinsic __builtin__clz()'

Tags: c++, intrinsics, built-in

I use CLion and need to use some intrinsics but especially __builtin__clz() to calculate the index of the LSB.
I included the headerFile "intrin.h" but I get the error "__builtin__clz' was not declared in this scope
"

Comment: Try `__builtin_clz`(single underscore) instead?

Comment: Should be `int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)` I think. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html